# Prove $f$ injective implies $o(f(g)) = o(g)$.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Suppose $G_1,G_2$ are groups and $f:G_1 \to G_2$ is a homomorphism. Prove $f$ injective implies $o(f(g)) = o(g)  \space\forall g\in G$.

Suppose $g\in G , g'\in G$ such that $o(g)=n, f(g)=g'$. Then

$$\begin{align}
e&=f(e)\\
&=f(g^n)\\
&=(f(g))^n\\
&=(g')^n,
\end{align}$$

which implies $o(g')\mid n.$

I can't see how using the injectivity helps me find that $o(f(g)) = o(g)$.

Help please.

Comment: What your final line proves is that $o(g')\vert n$, not $n\vert o(g')$.

Comment: @DavidSheard typo , thanks

Comment: Since $o(g)=n$, $g,g^2,\dots,g^n$ are distinct elements. But also $o(g')=n$ iff $g', g'^2,g'^3,\dots,g'^n$ are also distinct elements. Can you use the injectivity of $f$ to help prove this?

Comment: @DavidSheard Yes ! Thanks !

Comment: If $(g')^k=e$, then $e=f(g)^k=f(g^k)$, so by injectivity $g^k=e$ and $o(g)\mid k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group

$$\langle g\rangle=\{e,g,\dots, g^{n-1}\}$$

has $n$ distinct elements, since $|g|=n$.

Consider $g'^i=g'^j$ for some $i,j\in\{0,1,\dots, n-1\}$. Here $g'=f(g)$, so

$$\begin{align}
g'^i=g'^j&\implies f(g)^i=f(g)^j\\
&\implies f(g^i)=f(g^j)\quad(f\text{ is a homomorphism})\\
&\implies g^i=g^j\quad(f\text{ is injective})\\
&\implies i=j\quad(\text{these powers of }g\text{ are distinct}).
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the elements of $\{e,g',\dots, g'^{n-1}\}$ are distinct.

But $|f(g)|\mid |g|$.

Clearly, if $|g|$ is infinite, then so is $f(g)$ by injectivity, for suppose otherwise: then $|f(g)|=m$ would imply $f(g)^m=f(g)^{2m}$, which would mean $f(g^m)=f(g^{2m})$, giving $g^m=g^{2m}$ by injectivity; but then $|g|$ would be finite.

Thus $|f(g)|=|g|$.

Answer (score 3):

Now let $o(g')=k$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
e &= (g')^k\\
&= (f(g))^k\\
&= f(g^k).
\end{align*}$$
By injectivity of $f$, $g^k=e$, so $n\mid k$.

You can make the argument work for infinite order without having to divide into parts by noting that your original argument and this one show that for any integer $k$,
$$ g^k =e\iff (f(g))^k=e.$$
Since the order of $x$ is defined as the nonnegative generator of the ideal of integers $k$ for which $x^k=0$, this proves $g$ and $f(g)$ have the same order.

Answer (score 2):

Since the $n$ elements of $\langle g\rangle=\{e_1,g,g^2,\dots,g^{n-1}\}$ are pairwise distinct, then *by the injectivity of $f$* so are those of the set $\{f(e_1)=e_2,f(g),f(g^2),\dots,f(g^{n-1})\}=\{e_2,f(g),f(g)^2,\dots,f(g)^{n-1}\}$. You have already proved that $o(f(g))\mid n$, and now we have proved that there are $n$ distinct powers of $f(g)$. Therefore, $o(f(g))=n$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative proof to the ones presented so far (although in essence all such proofs are the same).

Let $f: G_1 \to G_2$ be injective, and $g \in G_1$. Let $H = \langle g \rangle \leq G_1$. Then $f$ restricts to an injective map $h = f|_H : H \to G_2$, so since $f|_H(H) = \langle h(g) \rangle$,

$$|\langle h(g) \rangle | = |f|_H(H)| = |H| = |\langle g \rangle|$$

Therefore $\text{ord}(f(g)) = \text{ord}(g)$.

Comment: I think that the point is precisely to prove that $f|_H(H) = \langle h(g) \rangle$, namely that $h(\langle g\rangle) = \langle h(g) \rangle$.

Comment: It's always true that $h(\langle g \rangle) = \langle h(g) \rangle$. Injectivity comes into play at the line $|f|_H(H)| = |H|$.

Comment: Right, I got the point. Thanks.